# How can you animate the tabs themselves (not just the content) with jQuery tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, tabs

I have looked but cannot find if it is possible to animate the transition from one tab to another. I am referring to the actual tabs, not just the content of the tabs.

I would like the previous tab button to fade out while the clicked-on tab button fades in.

The following only animates the content:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ hide: 'fadeOut', show: 'fadeIn' });
```

Is this possible?

The HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fragment-1">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-2">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#fragment-3">Three</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="fragment-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh     euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
  <div id="fragment-3">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your html?

Comment: HTML added as requested. This is just standard markup. Nothing fancy, but I would like the tabs to transition as well as the content of the tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

By using .newTab and .oldTab in beforeActivate, I was able to animate the actual tabs in coordination with the content:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ hide: 'fadeOut', show: 'fadeIn' });

$( "#tabs").tabs({
beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
 ui.newTab.animate({
opacity: 0
}, 0, function() {ui.newTab.animate({
opacity: 1
}, 0, function() {});});   

 ui.oldTab.animate({
opacity: 0
}, 400, function() {ui.oldTab.animate({
opacity: 1
}, 0, function() {});});

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the JQuery Tabs widget has an option for this. You could easily manually code that to add and remove a class and animate it (using JQ on click though maybe.

$("#tabs ul li").bind("click", function(){
    $("#tabs ul li").removeClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
    $(this).addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active");
});

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the following, but it still does not animate the tabs. Any insight into what I have wrong?
$("#tabs ul li").bind("click", function(){ $("#tabs #subtabs6  ul li").removeClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active").animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000, function() {}); $(this).addClass("ui-tabs-active ui-state-active").animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000, function() {}); 
  });